# Foward / backward Cauchy problem (with perturbation)

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

Let $f \in \mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}^{n+1},\mathbb{R}^n)$, and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^+$, such that $0<a<a+\epsilon \leq b$ (where $\epsilon >0$).

and we define the following ODEs : Assuming the existence of an absolutely continuous solution $x(.)$ defined on $[0,b]$.
$$\begin{cases}
\dot x(t)=f(t,x(t)) & t\in[0,b]\\
x(a)=x_a,
\end{cases}
$$
Now, we introduce a small perturbation, and I want to prove that $x_{\epsilon}$ is defined on [0,b] for small $\epsilon$ (i.e $\exists \delta >0 \,\, \epsilon < \delta \text{ such that }x_{\epsilon} \text{ defined on } [0,b] $).
$$\begin{cases}
\dot x_{\epsilon}(t)=f(t,x_{\epsilon}(t)) & t\in[0,b]\\
x_{\epsilon}(a+\epsilon)=(1+\epsilon)x_a,
\end{cases}
$$
We have the existence of a neighborhood of $(a+\epsilon)$ : $]a+\epsilon-\nu,a+\epsilon+\nu[$ for some $\nu>0$.

First of all, I tried to prove that $x_{\epsilon}$ is defined at $0$ : $\exists \delta >0 \,\, \epsilon < \delta \text{ such that }x_{\epsilon} \text{ defined at } 0$.

By contradiction, we have for all $\delta>0$, $\exists \epsilon<\delta \text{ such that } x_{\epsilon} \text{ is not defined at } 0$ i.e $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}x_{\epsilon}(y)=\infty.$
So if we tend $\delta $ to $0$, we will get $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}x(y)=\infty.$ which is impossible.

Comment: @amsmath yes thanks

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @PaulSinclair proving $x_{\epsilon}$ is global : defined on $[0,b]$

Comment: Is it important that $f$ is only continuous, but not necessarily Lipschitz in the second argument? With a local Lipschitz constant one would get $$\|x_ϵ(t)-x(t)\|\le e^{L(t-(a+ϵ))}\|x_ϵ(a+ϵ)-x(a+ϵ)\|=e^{L(t-(a+ϵ))}\|(1+ϵ)x_a-x(a+ϵ)\|$$ as long as $x_ϵ$ stays in the domain where the Lipschitz constant is defined. One should be able to calibrate this setup so that this interval extends to $[0,b]$.